# ol.interaction.Select not working on OpenLayers 4

Tags: openlayers

I have a single map and I want to add single click intergration to click to select map objects. But I write some code below, it's not working.

```
IMSMap.map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Select());
```

and tried this

```
IMSMap.map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.click
  }));
```

both are not working, I clicked and nothing to happen.
I want to my map works like this sample in this url
http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/select-features.html

Comment: I guess you should write `map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.click
  }));`  or write `IMSMap.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.click
  }));`

Comment: IMSMap is my general js object and .map properties type is ol.map, your advices same things with mine and still nothing to happen.

Comment: I simplified the openlayer's official example  https://codepen.io/himyata/pen/jLaqOV . Might be another problem in your code.